# Join and rename on multiple column in less queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I am actually developing a little site where I use MySQL for a database Server, but I'm stuck on a problem.

I have a table that contains the user, called "user",
User contain 3 columns, "username", "avatar" and "user_id"

Now I have a second table, called "wedding", which contains 6 columns: The user_id of 4 different users (called mid1, mid2, tid1 and tid2), then wed_id, and wed_date.

My purpose is to get in a single query (the number of queries of the site are limited, so that's why I want to use the minimum amount of queries) all data of a wedding row, and the user_name and avatar of the 4 user referenced in wedding, and to avoid duplication, I would have the username of the first user as username1, the second user username2 and so on, and the same things for the avatar.

First I don't know if it's possible, that's why I'm completely stuck on how that query would be, so if someone know how to create such queries I'll thanks him a lot!

Comment: Can you setup a SQL Fiddle? http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: What particularly is the difficulty here? You don't know how to join? You don't know how to resolve more than one reference? You don't know how to "rename" columns? In other words, is there a simpler version of the problem that you *would* be able to solve, so that we could get the idea of what you are having issues with here?

Comment: I know how to join as I know how to rename, The multiple references is what make problem for me. And my main problem is to do that in only one query, As for SQL fiddle, seems like he is down, I'm searching for an alternative to give you more precise infos about my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select wed_id, wed_date,
    user1.username as username1, user1.avatar as avatar1, 
    user2.username as username2, user2.avatar as avatar2, 
    user3.username as username3, user3.avatar as avatar3, 
    user4.username as username4, user4.avatar as avatar4
from wedding 
    inner join user as user1 on user1.user_id = wedding.mid1
    inner join user as user2 on user2.user_id = wedding.mid2
    inner join user as user3 on user3.user_id = wedding.tid1
    inner join user as user4 on user4.user_id = wedding.tid2
```

If some of the foreign keys may be NULL then consider "left join" as well.

Comment: Thanks you! exactly what I was looking for, I didn't knew you could join the same table multiple times with different names, you learned me something, thanks you!